# How to get audio to stop on next scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

```
import flash.media.Sound;

var sound1 = new MenuTheme();

sound1.play(1000);
```

Got this code to play, but now I want it to stop on its dedicated frame after I switch to a new one. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(currentFrame == 2(your dedicated frame)
 { 
    sound1.stop();
 }
```

One more thing, use a sound library, it helps a lot!