# Audio ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

```
import flash.media.Sound;

var sound1 = new MenuTheme();

sound1.play(1000);

 if(currentFrame == 2(your dedicated frame)
 { 
    sound1.stop();
 }
```

It comes up with Error TypeError: Error #1006 I want it to stop on the next frame after clicking a button otherwise this error stops everything :(

[How to get audio to stop on next scene?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23317460/how-to-get-audio-to-stop-on-next-scene/23450067?noredirect=1#comment35946344_23450067)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking to see if the current frame is 2, I would suggest stopping the sound when the button is clicked, like so (with an example button named buttonToNextFrame):

```
buttonToNextFrame.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToNextFrame);
function goToNextFrame (e: MouseEvent) {
      sound1.stop();
      //Other stuff you would like done when the button is pressed.
      gotoAndStop(2);
}
```

If there is a way to bypass the button to get to frame 2 and you still want the sound to stop, then you would have to either:

- stop the sound in every event/way used to get to frame 2
- stop the sound directly on frame 2 with a plain `sound1.stop()`

Let me know if you have any further questions!